Private Sub Worksheet_Change for entering dates without "/" unexpectedly stops running after 3 dates are entered
I'm trying to make a simple code that can make data entry a little bit faster. A user should be able to type 13 for Jan 3rd, 22 for Feb 2nd, 310 for Mar 10th, 1005 for Oct 5th, 1220 for Dec 20th. All of the dates would use today's year.
The code seems to break, but still function, just incorrectly after performing as expected for 3 cells. Then, if I delete the column or reload the workbook it works again as intended, but only for the first 3 cells.
By still function, just incorrectly, it treats 13 as Jan 13, 1990; 22 as Jan 22, 1990; 310 as the 310th day of 1990; 1005 as the 1,220th day after Dec 31, 1899; and etc.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Selection.Count > 1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        TLen = Len(Target)
        DaV = Target

        If TLen = 2 Then
            DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 1), Right(Target, 1))
        ElseIf TLen = 3 Then
            DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 1), Right(Target, 2))
        ElseIf TLen = 4 Then
            DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 2), Right(Target, 2))
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = DaV
        Target.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


still function, just incorrectly - how so?

For your code to work at all, you need to make sure the cells are formatted as Text before you enter the date, and you cannot apply a different NumberFormat, because if you do, you will lose the ability to re-enter another date in the same cell. Because Excel will parse your text input in non-text cells, and your Target in Worksheet_Change will already contain the automatically parsed Date, not your raw text input.

Change TLen = Len(Target) to CTLen = Len(Target.Value2)

But why would it act as if the TLen is not equal to 2, 3, or 4?

Because Excel autoformats the value to "yyyy-mm-dd" and the len becomes 10. This is one of the main reasons why I prefer using .Value2 in lieu of .Value. You may also want to read up on What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?

Also since you are working with Events in Worksheet_Change event, I would recommend using Error Handling as shown HERE

Siddharth, I tried changing TLen = Len(Target) to CTLen = Len(Target.Value2)  but i get a debug error on this line.
DaV = DateValue(Year(Now) & "-" & Left(Target, 1) & "-" & Right(Target, 1))

Do not change anything else. just the line that I mentioned and your original code will work.

It works, but only for the first 3 entries.  Then it breaks with debug error mismatch.

One more thing... You have to replace Target with Target.Value2 Posting an answer. one moment.

@SiddharthRout Of what use is Target.Value2 if Excel has already replaced the user's input (which the OP is hoping to parse) with a parsed date (which makes .Value2 something like 44238)?

One moment @GSerg. Posting an answer which will also take care of others issues and checks

Explanation
The main problem with your code is that you are using .Value instead of .Value2
You may want to read up on What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?
The problem is when you format a cell, Excel automatically copies the format to the next cell below it. And since you are using .Value, the code picks up the formatted value. So it is a good idea to store the value in a variable and use that.
So if you put a breakpoint in your code at TLen = Len(Target) you will get 10 instead of 4 for 1005. If you use .Value2 you will get 4 and not 10 or 5(For Date stored as number).


I have also added few more checks. For example when extracted month is greater then 12 or extracted day is greater than 31 and also for the leap year. I have also added a check for Strings else you will get an error for string which have 2-4 length.
I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. If you still do, then let me know.
Code
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '~~> Error Handling
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    '~~> Check if there is more than one cell was changed
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim D As Long, M As Long
    Dim TLen As Long
    Dim dt As String
    Dim FinalDate As Date
    
    '~~> Check if the change happened in column C
    If Not Intersect(Columns(3), Target) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Get the value of changed cell
        dt = Target.Value2
        '~~> Get the length
        TLen = Len(dt)
        
        '~~> String check
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value2) Then GoTo Letscontinue
        
        '~~> FIRST CHECK: If the length is not as expected do nothing
        If TLen < 2 Or TLen > 4 Then GoTo GoToFormatAndExit
        
        '~~> Get the date and month
        Select Case TLen
            Case 2
                D = Right(dt, 1)
                M = Left(dt, 1)
            Case 3
                D = Right(dt, 2)
                M = Left(dt, 1)
            Case 4
                D = Right(dt, 2)
                M = Left(dt, 2)
        End Select
        
        '~~> FEW CHECKS: TO get correct dates
        '~~> Month more than 12
        If M > 12 Then GoTo GoToFormatAndExit
        '~~> Date more than 31
        If D > 31 Then GoTo GoToFormatAndExit
        '~~> Leap year
        If D > 28 And M = 2 And isLeapYear(Year(Now)) Then GoTo GoToFormatAndExit
        
        '~~> Construct final date
        FinalDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), M, D)
        
        '~~> Check if Excel created an incorrect date
        If Year(FinalDate) <> Year(Now) Then GoTo GoToFormatAndExit
        
        Target = FinalDate
        Target.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End If
    
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
GoToFormatAndExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    '~~> Excel changes the format so keep it as general
    Target.NumberFormat = "General"
    Exit Sub
    
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub

Public Function isLeapYear(Yr As Integer) As Boolean
    isLeapYear = (Month(DateSerial(Yr, 2, 29)) = 2)
End Function

In Action

Disclaimer:
I may have missed few more checks as I have not thouroughly tested this. Feel free to improvise the code.

And 112 is supposed to be Jan 12th or Nov 2nd? Your format is inconclusive and may generate errors.
My idea of solution.
When you enter a few dates into a column, Excel thinks you'll want to continue to enter dates and treats unformatted numbers as serial date numbers. It converts them to dates before the Change procedure runs, and the Change procedure gets the converted value.
You can protect yourself against this by prefixing the entry with an apostrophe. You can also add an appropriate snippet in the code that will do it for you.
But watch out for mistakes, because the DateSerial function used in your code doesn't validate the dates. Personally, I would prefer to use DataValue and error control.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Selection.Count > 1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If IsDate(Target) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target = "'" & CLng(Target)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        
        Dim TLen As Long, DaV
        TLen = Len(Target)
        DaV = Target

     '   If TLen = 2 Then
     '       DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 1), Right(Target, 1))
     '   ElseIf TLen = 3 Then
     '       DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 1), Right(Target, 2))
     '   ElseIf TLen = 4 Then
     '       DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 2), Right(Target, 2))
     '   Else
     '       Exit Sub
     '   End If
     
        On Error GoTo NotDate
        If TLen = 2 Then
            DaV = DateValue(Year(Now) & "/" & Left(Target, 1) & "/" & Right(Target, 1))
        ElseIf TLen = 3 Then
            DaV = DateValue(Year(Now) & "/" & Left(Target, 1) & "/" & Right(Target, 2))
        ElseIf TLen = 4 Then
            DaV = DateValue(Year(Now) & "/" & Left(Target, 2) & "/" & Right(Target, 2))
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = DaV
        Target.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
NotDate:
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = "Not a date"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


For a number, CLng(Target)  is the same as Target.Value2. But if the user enters a string in a cell, CLng(Target) will fail. Also you are overwriting the cell with Not a date. What if the user wants to retain the typed value?

These are details that can be dealt with in different ways. I assumed that only the correct dates would be entered in this column.

Because I want to understand how the function is working, and not use more code than I'm familiar with, I am using this approach.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Date
If Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
    TLen = Len(Target.Value2)
    DaV = Target
    On Error GoTo DateEntryError
    If (TLen >= 1) And (TLen <= 4) Then
        Target.NumberFormat = "@"
        Select Case TLen
            Case 2
                DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 1), Right(Target, 1))
            Case 3
                DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 1), Right(Target, 2))
            Case 4
                DaV = DateSerial(Year(Now), Left(Target, 2), Right(Target, 2))
            End Select
        Else
        DaV = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy"
    Target = DaV
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End If
Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLING SECTION'
DateEntryError:
    MsgBox "Date may be entered wrong. Enter 13 for 1/03 (Jan 3), 218 for 2/18 (Feb 18), 1005 for 10/05 (Oct 5), 1231 for 12/31, and so on.  This message will display when clearing contents of a single cell and when revising an existing date."
    Resume Next

End Sub

